# j code to Chop insignificant digits

Tags: j

I saw this piece of J code

```
(**+)&.+.
```

in RosettaCode FFT section. It is supposed to clean up insignificant digits of FFT result. For example

(**+)&.+. 4e_16j2

gives

```
0j2
```

It is similar to `Chop` function of Mathematica for example.

However

```
(**+)&.+. _4j_2
```

gives

```
4j2 (instead of _4j_2)
```

which is obviously incorrect.

The question is what is the correct way in J to chop off insignificant digits?

Comment: Change it to `(**|)&.+.`. Short story: `+` is complex conjugate; not what's wanted; `|` is absolute value, probably what was intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`round` in the "numeric" package is `[ * [: <. 0.5 + %~`. You can use it as follows:

```
   require 'numeric'
   (0.01&round)&.+. _1.5j_4.6 4e_16j2 2j4e_16
_1.5j_4.6 0j2 2
```

The code given in the question, corrected to use `|` instead of `+` is `(**|)&.+.` and it is using a byproduct of operating on numbers to round them. You are taking each part of a complex number (`&.+.`) and multiplying (`*`) its absolute value (`|`) by its sign (`*`). You could achieve the same sort of effect by adding and subtracting a constant from your number with something like `10j10 -~ 10j10 + ]`.

`[ * [: <. 0.5 + %~` doesn't use any byproducts, but rather directly rounds the number to the desired precision. `%~` divides `y` by `x`, so that if you're rounding 0.3579 to two decimal places, indicated by an `x` of 0.01, your first step gets you 35.79. You then add 0.5 (`0.5 +`) and take the floor (`[: <.`), which is the same as rounding to zero places (35.79 + 0.5 = 36.29, the floor of which is 36). The final step is to multiply by `x` (`[ *`) to undo what was done with `%~`.

While it is tempting to create a complex version of `round` with `[ * [: <. 0.5j0.5 + %~`, using `<.` on a complex number produces the [complex floor](http://www.jsoftware.com/papers/eem/complexfloor1.htm), which is probably not be what you are after. If you expect the imaginary and real components to be rounded independently, go with applying `round` under `+.`. I think the following gives you a taste of how the complex floor is different than taking the floor of each part of the complex number:

```
   <. 0.7 0j0.7 0.6j0.7 0.7j0.6
0 0 0j1 1
```

This helps explain the following:

```
   1 ([ * [: <. 0.5j0.5 + %~) 0.2 0j0.2 0.1j0.2 0.2j0.1
1 0j1 0j1 1
```

"Rounding" `0.2` to `1` caught me off-guard, but it is because `0.2 + 0.5i0.5` = `0.7i0.5`, and `<. 07j0.5` has a complex floor of `1`. The same goes for `0j0.2` "rounding" to `0j1`.

If you just want the nearest number where both parts of the complex number are integers, you can use `([: <. 0.5 + ])&.+.`:

```
   ([: <. 0.5 + ])&.+. 0.2 0j0.2 0.1j0.2 0.2j0.1
0 0 0 0
   ([: <. 0.5 + ])&.+. 0.7 0j0.7 0.6j0.7 0.7j0.6
1 0j1 1j1 1j1
```

Answer (score 2):

The monad `+` (as opposed to the *dyad* `+`) is "[complex conjugate](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d100.htm)", which is the culprit in producing `4j2` as opposed to `_4j_2`.

The editor responsible for `(**+)&.+.` on RosettaCode probably intended to use `|`, [absolute value](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d230.htm), in place of `+`, thus:

```
    (**|)&.+. _4j_2 4e_16j2
 _4j_2 0j2
```

Comment: As a P.S., `round` in "numeric" package is `[ * [: <. 0.5 + %~`. E.g. `1e_3 round 1.12345678` gives `1.123`

Comment: @Eelvex Yeah, the issue with `round` is it wasn't designed to work with complex numbers, e.g. both `round _4j_2 4e_16j2` and `round&.+. round _4j_2 4e_16j2` are identically `_4j_2 4e_16j2`.

Comment: @DanBron `1 round _4j_2 4e_16j2` results in `_4j_2 0j2`

Comment: Unfortunately, `1 round 0j4.5` results in `1j4`, which is . . . quite wrong. I'm working on an answer based on `round` but complex-friendly.

Comment: I think `(1&round)&.+. _1.5j_4.6 4e_16j2 2j4e_16` gives the correct behavior: `_1j_5 0j2 2`

Answer (score 0):

The one I've been using is `(**@|)` which does not have this problem.

Specifically in this case, this seems to do what you want:

```
(**@|)&.+.
```